# Checking for a nonleft turn in Graham's scan

Tags: algorithm, convex-hull, grahams-scan

Following the description of the Graham's scan algorithm from Cormen's "Introduction to Algorithms" I found out the following note:

> By checking for a nonleft turn, rather than just a right turn, this test precludes the possibility of a straight angle at a vertex of the resulting convex hull. We want no straight angles, since no vertex of a convex polygon may be a convex combination of other vertices of the polygon.

Could someone explain please, why we should skip straight angles at vertices of the resulting convex hull? It is not clear why

> no vertex of a convex polygon may be a convex combination of other vertices of the polygon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is true because, by definition, convex hull is the smallest convex set of points that contains the polygon.